Firebase firestore dealing with timestamp issues
My app lets user create their financial profile such as their assets, expenses, etc. This is stored as a document in the Firestore with that day's timestamp and looks like below:
{
Date: October 8, 2024 at 12:00:00 AM UTC-5,
annualIncome: 25000,
monthlyExpenses: 5000
}

The logic to create the date in the mobile app is
Date:Timestamp
...

this.Date = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(),0,0,0,0));

In the Firebase function, I want to create a new document after 24 hours and my logic is like below
      const finColRef = db.collection("users/" + <id> + "/finance")
      const fQuerySnapshot = await finColRef.orderBy("Date").limit(1).get()
      fQuerySnapshot.forEach(async(doc:any) => {
        let data = doc.data()        
        const dt = new Date()
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)
        data.Date = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0))
        await finColRef.add(data)
      });

This creates a new document and the date now shows:
{
Date: October 9, 2024 at 7:00:00 PM UTC-5,
annualIncome: 25000,
monthlyExpenses: 5000
}

The time component when created on this date is different than what came from when it was created on the client side. This will create problems for me as every user may have a different timezone. How do I consistently handle this?

Firestore timestamp objects only store the offset from the Unix epoch with a microsecond precision. It doesn't have any timezone encoded into it, that's why you get that result. But please note, that not only Firestore but many other databases don't care about the timezone when it comes to timestamp objects, it's all about a "point in time".
If you want to perform a test, please open the Firebase Console and check the value of a timestamp field, for example, the value of the Date field. You'll see that the time is displayed using the local timezone that your device is a part of. Bear in mind that it doesn't matter in which timezone the client is. A "point in time" is the same no matter where the user is located around the world.
If you are converting the timestamp to a Date object, that date object will be converted itself in the user device's local timezone, similar to what is happening in the Firebase Console. As also mentioned in one of the previous answers, the timezone of the Firestore timestamp is UTC.
If you want to get the Date object that corresponds to a specific timezone, you should use some specialized classes such as TimeZone. I recently also found a list of all available time zones. Perhaps it will help.

Hey Vivek. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
